# Troubleshooting monerod segmentation fault

Tags: full-node, synchronization, daemon, ubuntu

I was running a fresh monero full node through it first synchronization.

After a long while through the synchronization noticed the daemon became stuck synchronizing a particular block, so I orderly requested "stop_daemon", which it happily obliged without any issues and the daemon stopped normally.

When I tried to start the daemon again it crashed with a segmentation fault signal shortly after:

```
**********************************************************************
You are now synchronized with the network. You may now start monero-wallet-cli.

Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.
**********************************************************************
2017-09-24 16:23:35.510 [P2P1]  WARN    net.dns src/common/dns_utils.cpp:487    WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received
2017-09-24 16:23:36.187 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:305 [47.20.163.52:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1377819 -> 1406197 [Your node is 28378 blocks (39 days) behind]
SYNCHRONIZATION started
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've attached some files for details:

- [Command prompt log](https://pastebin.com/Sm1sU7XZ)
- [GDB log](https://pastebin.com/VEDjcNWR)

> **Monero Version:** CLI 0.11.0 64-bit
>
> **HDD Remaining Space:** 320GB
>
> **RAM:** 8GB
>
> **OS:** Ubuntu 17.04 (x64)
>
> **uname -a:** Linux home-laptop 4.10.0-35-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 13 07:46:59
>   UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Could you try to apply this [PR](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2492)?

Comment: @dEBRUYNE Wasn't it merged into the latest build? Either way I will compile monero later in the day with that patch.

Comment: Nope, it's not included in the release binaries. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE Well, its synchronizing from scratch now. 
Oddly enough, it was unable to resume synchronization of the blockchain state belonging to the failed monerod daemon, but it wouldn't crash either, just became stuck at a particular block trying over and over to sync it.
I will let you know once it goes through the block it was stuck.

Comment: `./monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks <arg>` might've helped with that, but it's too late for that now. Anyway, let me know if it syncs past `1377819 `.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE Synchronization is completed. All good, thank you!

Comment: All right, good to hear!